# How to capture images with the camera in a constant period without press any key in android?

Tags: android

I want to capture images with the camera in a constant period without press any key and compare consecutive images to detect motions.
this project is very important for me. please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom camer to take image , then use Timer thread to take picture at regular interval by calling takePicture() function of camera class

Answer (score 0):

1 - Explore the [`Camera class`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html), it is easy to understand.

2 - Use a `[Handler][2]` or a [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to schedule the auto photo taking.

It seems quite simple, actually. There are several examples online on how to user handlers and timers, and the camera class is simple to use.